# Обработка одинаковых одновременных реквестов

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Есть метод в контроллере апи, этот метод принимает модель сущности. Внутри проверяется, существует ли такая сущность и если нет, то мы ее создаем. Если сущность уже есть, то мы ничего не делаем.

Возникла проблема при куче параллельных одинаковых запросов к этому апи, т.е. с одной и той же сущностью. Если запросы идут совсем рядом, то для них обоих сущность не существует и создается в обоих случаях, хотя нам нужно только 1 создание.

Вопрос: как правильно избежать таких ситуаций? Сейчас у нас несколько таких методов с похожим поведением в приведенном кейсе.

**UPD**: сущности создаются в Mongo, но я не вижу возможности делать проверку ее средствами. Речь идет не о простой проверке уникальных полей в коллекции. Связи сложнее. Да, просто с полем Name может помочь [Unique Constraints on Arbitrary Fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/unique-constraints-on-arbitrary-fields/), но что делать, если уникальной должна быть комбинация полей, к примеру Name + Type? Или вообще по неполному совпадению одного из филдов и полному другого?

В общем, интересует возможность делать проверку именно из кода.

```
[HttpPost("entity")]
public async Task<EntityView> CreateEntity(
    [FromBody] EntityModel payload)
{
    var existedEntity = await GetEntityByName(payload.Name);
    if (existedEntity != null)
    {
        return existedEntity.ToView();
    }

    var result = await CreateEntity(payload);
    return result.ToView();
}
```

Comment: В базе Вам нужно сделать поле `Name` с ограничением UNIQUE, чтобы избежать повторной вставки объекта с одним и тем же именем. Ну и отлавливать соответствующее исключение, бросаемое SQL-провайдером при вставке уже существующего объекта, и дальше уже можно вернуть ответ пользователю, что сущность с таким именем уже существует.

Comment: Это хороший вариант, но: 1. у нас не sql-база, работаем с mongo. 2. конкретно поле Name - не должно быть уникальным во всей коллекции, там могут быть разные ограничения, в том числе из других коллекций, именно поэтому проверка на existedEntity делается из кода, она может быть значительно сложнее, здесь для примера я упростил.

Comment: Здесь напрашивается какой-то lock условия проверки и создания, но возможно, есть более корректный способ для подобных вещей, у меня мало опыта с этим. к сожалению)

Comment: _у нас не sql-база, работаем с mongo_ - почему этого нет в вопросе? Это самая важная информация, потому что именно монга должна проверять уникальность. [Unique Constraints on Arbitrary Fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/unique-constraints-on-arbitrary-fields/)

Comment: Вы используете .NET или .NET Core? Это _разные_ технологии. Оставьте одну метку, другую удалите.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо за замечание, поправил! Но боюсь, предложенный вами вариант не совсем подходит, я написал об этом в комментарии выше и UPD секции вопроса.

Comment: Думаю самым подходящим здесь будет при условии множества параллельных запросов с одинаковым payload - это действительно ставить lock.Но lock будет работать только с синхронным кодом. Для асинхронного кода можно использовать например - SemaphoreSlim.